# Android App display 0.0 instead of the result

Tags: java, android

thanks for help me, I'm learning programming with java and android, my problem is that I develop an app that convert from miles to km and viceversa and show the result in the middle of the screen in big number, but when hit convert the result is just 0.0, I want to know how to display the result.

here are my code

```
 //Method called when click the button
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.radioButton:
            RadioButton milesButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
            RadioButton kmButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
            if(text.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
    }
    Double inputValue = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

    if (rb.isChecked()) {
        text.setText(String.valueOf(Conversor.convertMilesToKm(inputValue)));
        rb.setChecked(false);
        rb2.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        text.setText(String.valueOf(Conversor.convertKmToMiles(inputValue)));
        rb2.setChecked(false);
        rb.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

This is my main.xml file

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<EditText
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/conversion_number"
    android:hint="@string/in_message"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/convert"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/conversion_number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/conversion_number"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="175dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="380dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Miles"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Kilometers"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

</RadioGroup>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bigText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bigText"
        android:textSize="150dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

My converter class

```
package com.algenis.speedcoverter;

public class Conversor {
    //convert to miles
    public static double convertMilesToKm(double miles) {
        double miles_rand;
        miles_rand = (miles * 1.60934);
        return (int)Math.round(miles_rand);
    }
    // convert to km
    public static double convertKmToMiles(double km) {
        double km_rand;
        km_rand = (km * 0.621371);
        return (int)Math.round(km_rand);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `inputValue`? (And just use a `double`; you're unnecessarily creating and discarding a wrapper object.)

Comment: I want display my result in the middle of the screen as you see in this image. [Click Here](http://i1356.photobucket.com/albums/q723/algenisromero/Android%20Apps/device-2013-12-22-124740_zps3eaefaaa.png)

Comment: @Algenis maybe you want to pick a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return (int)Math.round(miles_rand);` to `return(double)Math.round(miles_rand);`

and `return (int)Math.round(km_rand);` to `return (double)Math.round(km_rand);`

Comment: I want display my result in the middle of the screen as you see in this image. [Click Here](http://i1356.photobucket.com/albums/q723/algenisromero/Android%20Apps/device-2013-12-22-124740_zps3eaefaaa.png)

Comment: Have the container declared as RelativeLayout.  Then your TextView should declare the attribute **centerInParent="true"**

Comment: @Algenis Klaus66 gave you the answer ^

Answer (score 2):

If you use integers, you'll only get integers!

So:

```
return (int)Math.round(km_rand);
```

and also

```
return (int)Math.round(miles_rand);
```

will return **0** if km_rand (or miles_rand) is **0.1234** (**less than 0.5**) and **1** if it is **0.5678** (**0.5 or more**)

So it should be:

```
return (double)Math.round(km_rand);
```

and also

```
return (double)Math.round(miles_rand);
```

But Math.round return an int... so, you better remove it!

So, FINALLY, it should be:

```
return km_rand;
```

and also

```
return miles_rand;
```

**[EDIT]**

Also, you are using String.valueOf, which converts to a **long** (which, in turn, is an **integer**).

You should be using:

```
myTextView.setText(Float.toString(myNumber));
```

Comment: Thanks, but still show me 0.0, I use a TextView for display the result, but when input any number to convert, the result always is 0.0

Comment: See my edited answer... you're doing a reconversion when assigning to the TextViews text... You should be careful with explicit and **implicit** type casts.

Comment: I want display my result in the middle of the screen as you see in this image. [Click Here](http://i1356.photobucket.com/albums/q723/algenisromero/Android%20Apps/device-2013-12-22-124740_zps3eaefaaa.png)